# Chrome - Microphone blocked even if it shows allowed

Tags: google-chrome, google-speech-api, webspeech-api

I am trying to implement and use the Chrome Speech API on my website but I'm not able to do it. The response I receive is that the "Permission to use microphone is blocked" but it really isn't. Microphone settings in Chrome are clearly showing that I don't have sites blocked and that the system should it least ask.

[image]

It is not a problem with the website because I have performed tests on other computers and it is working fine. I would like to figure out the settings/preferences that need to be readjusted in order to make this work.

In addition to this, in C:\Users\MY-USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences I was able to see entries for my site and I removed them but nothing changed. I tried also (not in order:

1- Reset Chrome.
2- Uninstalling/reinstalling Chrome. Manually removing files and registry entries.
3- Run Chrome in incognito mode.
4- Run ChromeCleanup Tool
5- Not working on Chrome Canary.
6- Every computer was tested on the same internet connection.

[image]

I am not sure what else I can do about this.

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess the API shows as blocked at the point in which it shows the prompt, then once the prompt is dismissed you need to try again

Comment: Also what are you doing with selenium, you have it tagged but no mention in the question.